# Newbie: developing in a remote docker @ aws ec2

Tags: docker, openssh, visual-studio-code

I'm newbie and needing help. Currently playing with following setup:

remote machine

- an AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu 18.
- Sec group: SSH - myIp port 22, http
- install docker and docker-compose
- composing odoo and postgres as services
- using either docker or docker-compose: both are ok

my local pc

- is win10 with VSCode 1.37
- installed ext: vs code remote development, docker, ..
- in terminal: ssh to remote machine is running well. including docker/docker-compose exec
- Inside VS Code, Remote-SSH to remote machine is also ok. Folder open to home is also ok.

However, I can't do debugging and using VS Code other capabilities such as postgres ext.

Then I revisit the [VS Code Remote Development site](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) 
but getting lost. Then moving into 'Developing inside a Container' part. Since the docker is in a remote machine then in particular following: [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-advanced#_developing-inside-a-container-on-a-remote-docker-host). In specific is using Option 2: Connect using an SSH tunnel. In 2nd step, in a terminal, when I run 'ssh -NL localhost:23750:/var/run/docker.sock user@hostname', the terminal just like freezing/nothing. Meanwhile, back in VS COde, Docker extension is keep on: 'Failed to connect'.

Then back to the terminal, Ctr-c and I got back my ssh prompt. Checking 'ssh -h', I can't find -N option. In the win10 setting: OpenSSH is installed.

Hence I really got lost. Please help.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There are too many pieces to answer well without more information. Try the vscode-docker github for more specific questions. This troubleshooting thread in particular may be helpful to you: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/1582#issuecomment-578882428